# Infinite loop occurs when indexing an array

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int vals[5];

    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        vals[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to learn C from a university tutorial. They mentioned that in the above code:

The for loop is reset when `i` reaches 5, and the program goes through the loop again, and again, repeatedly.

I couldn't understand why and I tried to figure it out in the [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com), it prints `6` (It's experimental now for C.) What's the proper output and why this occurs?

Comment: Your code invokes [UB](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), `vals[i]`will try to access `vals[5]`  which is out of bounds.

Comment: I tried your code on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/aAzej4) It gave output as `6`.

Comment: It _could_ result in an infinite loop due to UB, but it might not. One way it could result in an infinite loop is if (a) `i` is stored just after `vals`, (b) 0 is written to the storage location of `i` by the final iteration, and (c) `i` is read from this storage location by the compiler when performing the `i <= 5` test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array indices in C are 0 based. So if your array is of size 5, the indices go from 0 to 4.

You loop `for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)` reaches into index 5, which is outside the bounds of the array.

Reaching outside the bounds of a buffer is undefined behavior in C. Anything is allowed to happen. And your program glitching out completely, is one possible outcome.

It's *probably* happening because the array and the index are next to each other in memory. So `vals[5] = 0` sets `i` to zero. And henceforth the loop condition is forever satisfied.

Comment: This can be determined with something like `if(&i == &vals[5]) printf("Same address\n");`.

Answer (score 5):

This code invokes undefined bahavior.
Which of course means that what they stated, *could* actually happen. But this largely depends on many details.

When they state that `i` will be reset, they assume a certain location of the variables on the stack.
As soon as you execute

```
vals[i] = 0;
```

with `i==5` you *could* actually write to the location where `i` is stored. But on the other hand, `i` could just be hold in a register or somewhere else on the stack and you wouldn't get infinite loop.

Comment: Rather than "i could just be hold in an integer", "`i` could be stored elsewhere" would be clearer, I think.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to write register. Fixed that

Comment: Maybe a better word than reset would be corrupted.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes, but I wanted to use the same word used in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Variables having *automatic storage class* (variables created in a function except static variables) are created in the stack in C programming language.

The variables in your program are also created in stack. Therefore, the variables `i`, `vals[0]`, `vals[1]`, `vals[2]`, `vals[3]` and `vals[4]` can be found in stack.

**Remember: Array indices in C programming language starts from `0`. If the size of array is `n`, then indices go from 0 to (n-1).**

The `for` loop in your program is trying to access `vals[5]` when your index variable reaches `5`. Reaching outside the bounds of array is an **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR** in C. The result you have been seeing is one of the possible outcome. Since, `vals[5]` doesn't exist in your stack, you could be accessing memory location assigned to some other variable which could be memory location assigned to variable `i`. You can even get **Segmentation Fault** if you access an array out of it's bound (As I have mentioned above, the result is Undefined. You program may run without any segmentation fault or you may get it).

Consider the picture that I have created:

[image]

In your case, the array `vals` and the index `i` may be next to each other in stack. So, `vals[5] = 0` resets `i` to zero and hence infinite loop.